# "Ghost" 14px appearing when rendered on any browser, can't figure out why

Tags: html, css-tables

I have a css table that looks exactly the way I like it however the last row has instead of a 200px height a 214px but I have no idea where this is coming from. All images used are 200px in height and the css is also making use of that number.

This is what it [looks like](http://imgur.com/XVs8OTk) and the code is this:

CSS:

```
.table{display: table;width:800px;margin: 0 auto;}

.table img{border: none;}

.row{display: table-row;}

.col{display: table-column;}

.cell{display: table-cell;}

#kioskos{background-image: url('../img/thumbnails/kioskosnet.jpg');display:block;width: 250px;height: 200px;}
#kioskos:hover{background: url('../img/hovers/kioskos_h.png');}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
                           <div class="cell"><a id="kioskos" class="fancybox" rel="group" data-title="'Kioskos.net' Company's main website design. First
approach to web design." href="assets/img/fotos_grandes/kioskosnet1.jpg"></a></div>
                       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a `&nbsp;` in your last cell, that is positioning below your images.
remove it or use

```
.cell {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please post an url to the original web site?

with the information you provide, I can tell that probably the image is being vertically "centered" because the "extra" px are coming from the top and bottom of the table.